# asp.net mvc session state.. help?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-6, session-state

Has anyone ever eperienced session's being shared application wide?

My MVC application has the vanilla setup but for some reason, my sessions are being shared.

I didn't really think about it when I could switch between FF and IE and maintain a logged in state but now, I've noticed that I can switch machines too.

My web.config doesn't have anything in to setup the session state, so I assumed it was cookie based but it seem it's not.

Has anyone ever experienced this before and if so, how did you resolve it?

FYI: I'm running it on Server 2003 IIS6.

Thanks all!!

Gav

Comment: I assume you've tested all the obvious things like clearing browser data in one browser and then changing browsers? It shouldn't be sharing...

Comment: Nathan, I've cleared my cache, cookies etc. But that wouldn't make a difference as the cookies are not shared across both browsers and multiple computers. Thanks though, any other suggestions?

Comment: UPDATE!

The SessionID's are different between browsers/computers. So it seems the data is not being stored in the session (even though i'm using Session["Key"] = Value)

Any idea's?

Gav

Comment: @Gavin: Realized about 5 minutes after posting that I meant to say, "Logged out and cleared the session in another browser." :)

Comment: So if the SessionIDs are different, what exactly is being shared?

Comment: When logging in on my computer, I then went to another computer and went to the same url (not copy and pasted, but hand typed the root url) and it shows me as logged in. I then logged out on that machine, came back to my own machine and refreshed and it logged me out. Argh!! lol... Thanks for replying Nathan!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well would you believe it... Stupid static variables...

I thought by using a static private variable that it would help me by not doing as much work when getting the data, but as it seems, it was the root of evil. (doctor evil pinky)

Thanks everyone!

** **NOTE THIS IS HOW NOT!! TO DO IT** **

```
public class UserHelper
{
    private static UserSession _session;
    public static UserSession Session
    {
        get
        {
        // If we already have the session, don't get it
        // from the session state
        if (_session == null)
        {
            // Attempt to get the session from the
            // session state
            _session = GetUserSessionFromSession(HttpContext.Current.Session);
            if (_session == null)
            {
            // Create a new session object
            _session = new UserSession();
            }
        }
        return _session;
        }
        set
        {
        // Set the local value
        _session = value;
        // Add the object to the session state
        HttpContext.Current.Session["SMEUser"] = _session;
        }
    }

    public static void Logout()
    {
        Logout(HttpContext.Current.Session);
    }

    public static void Logout(HttpSessionState session)
    {
        _session = null;
        session.Clear();
    }

    public static UserSession GetUserSessionFromSession(HttpSessionState session)
    {
        // Get the session from the session state
        UserSession us = session["SMEUser"] as UserSession;
        return us;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you specifically using storing things in Session or are you seeing this in TempData  calls (which temporarily uses session as well)?

Comment: I'm storing them within the HttpSessionState (HttpContext.Current.Session)